# How to launch to an Android TV's Settings activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I've created a home launcher for my Android TV using the Android TV Activity in Android Studio.

It looks like the following:

[image]

What I'd like to accomplish is, if the user selects the `SETTINGS` option, it will launch the specific Android TV's settings page.

For example, I'm using a Ugoos-UT4 Android TV and their Settings page look like so:

[image]

I'm not looking to launch to a Settings template activity that Android Studio has, but the Settings Activity page of whichever device the apk is installed on.

I'm listening to items selection using the following:

```
private final class ItemViewSelectedListener implements OnItemViewSelectedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                                   RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row)
    {
        // If SETTINGS option selected, launch Android TV's settings page
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, I found out I can perform the following:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```